# How can I model AI Interactions across the entire game world without computing them individually?

Tags: ai, tilemap, maps, events, perlin-noise

I'm making a 2D top-down tile-based game in C++ using SDL2. The game uses a very large world map (think Dwarf Fortress).

My world terrain is generated using a noise function, another function is then used to build towns, model NPCs, etc. which are then saved to a local SQLite database (I'm using a database because NPC states, for example, are quite complicated - the database models their relationships with other NPCs, changing personalities, goals etc., and can be affected by player interactions with them as well).

At any point in time during play, the player is in some 'sector' of the world map. Currently, only interactions in the player's current sector are modeled (e.g. NPCs talking to each other, NPCs fighting each other etc.).

How can I model interactions across the entire world map, without the obvious computational problems of modelling every single interaction that occurs?

Is there some pattern which can generalise interactions?

The game uses time heavily (where a minute of game-time is a second in real-time, and thus in-game minutes, hours, days, months and years can be used). Could I somehow compute large-scale estimations of changes overtime? Some of these changes could be computed on player entry into the sector, based on how long it has been since the player has been in that sector (e.g. NPC getting older, dying of age etc.), but some changes should occur as they actually 'happen' (e.g. cross-sector things like an army or a trader travelling across the map).

Comment: in behavior tree papers it's sometime mentioned that one can have multiple levels of behavior, global, flock and individual.

Comment: There's an interesting concept called [Alibi Generation](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1119&context=hms) where you spawn NPCs without any prior history, but then retroactively make up a reason why the player encountered them there / what they were doing, depending on how much attention the player pays to each NPC. Kind of a simulation LoD, the bulk of your agents are cheap and only the ones the player interacts with get detailed out, while maintaining the perception of a complete & consistent world. It might not extend neatly to purely generated worlds though.

Comment: Have you actually tried to simulate the whole world and run into problems or made some guesses that it will not work based on experience with simulation of a part of the world and then extrapolating it? If not I would try expanding the simulation and see if there are really problems in performance. Depending on minimum requirements for your game it's very well possible that the computer can compute everything without too much effort.

Answer (score -1):

You must to divide your whole world into parts, and check is each of them is close/further from your position. It gives you priorities how frequently you should update your map part. Because there are some algorithms which allow to optimise such updates.

Comment: Welcome to game development stackexchange. Unfortunately this answer is not really helpful at all. The author of the question already says they are dividing their world into parts. And the information that "there are some algorithms" isn't helpful when you don't mention which algorithms you mean and how they work.